# How to re-enable a button after a checkbox is ticked?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I'm trying to get the the proceed button to get enabled after the checkbox has been ticked. I'm a beginner and not sure what I'm missing.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxProceed" runat="server" OnClick="chkProceed();" />

<asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Strings,ACC_ProceedToApplyForAccreditation%>"
                    OnClick="btnProceed_Click" CssClass="govuk-button" disabled/>
```

Here's what I've tried so far/found;

```
function chkProceed() {
        if (document.getElementById("chkBoxProceed").checked)
            document.getElementById("btnProceed").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("btnProceed").disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: And what issue you are facing with this code? You might want to use server side event handler for checkbox's checkchanged event. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f50501/oncheckedchanged-event-of-checkbox-control-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Nothing happens. The button stays disabled regardless of if the checkbox is ticked or not.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `OnClientClick` can't be understood by the browser.
You should use `OnClick` instead.

Change this code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxProceed" runat="server" OnClientClick="chkProceed();" />
```

To this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxProceed" runat="server" OnClick="chkProceed();" />
```

For more information [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135157/348589)

Comment: oops. I noticed that too. I have changed it OnClick but it still isn't working.

Comment: no errors - the button remains disabled and the checkbox does nothing.

Comment: can you try to remove the code inside `chkProceed` and put this `alert(document.getElementById("chkBoxProceed").checked);` so you can understand what is the status of the checkbox

Comment: curious enough, nothing happens.. There should be a pop-up right? Unless I'm mistaking 'alert' for something else?

Comment: are you sure you're using `OnClick` ?